# Center an ImageView (inside a RelativeLayout) to a LinearLayout (that is outside the RelativeLayout)

Tags: android, android-layout

I try to achieve something like the image below :

[image]

Except that the **Pin** should be center to the first group of labels & the **Flag** to the second one.

Here is the code I currently have :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    tools:context=".TestDesignActivity"
    >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/ll01"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/ll03"
        android:layout_alignTop="@id/ll02"
        android:layout_marginEnd="5dp"
        android:padding="5dp"
        >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/iv01"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:background="@drawable/ic_pin"
            />

        <View
            android:layout_width="2dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_above="@+id/iv02"
            android:layout_below="@+id/iv01"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:background="@color/md_grey_500"
            />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/iv02"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:background="@drawable/ic_flag"
            />
    </RelativeLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/ll02"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/ll01"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        >

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:ellipsize="end"
            android:maxLines="2"
            android:text="Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Quisque metus massa, aliquet id diam et, pellentesque tincidunt nibh. Suspendisse et sodales diam, nec porta dui. Sed."
            android:textColor="@color/black"
            android:textSize="16sp"
            />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:ellipsize="end"
            android:maxLines="3"
            android:text="Lorem ipsum dolor sit."
            android:textSize="12sp"
            />
    </LinearLayout>

    <Space
        android:id="@+id/space"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="10dp"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_below="@id/ll02"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/ll01"
        />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/ll03"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_below="@id/space"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/ll01"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        >

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:ellipsize="end"
            android:maxLines="2"
            android:text="Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Quisque metus massa, aliquet id diam et, pellentesque tincidunt nibh. Suspendisse et sodales diam, nec porta dui. Sed."
            android:textColor="@color/black"
            android:textSize="16sp"
            />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:ellipsize="end"
            android:maxLines="3"
            android:text="Lorem ipsum dolor sit."
            android:textSize="12sp"
            />
    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

I'm not quite sure if it's possible (in XML) to access from a child view to another view that isn't in the same "view level" ...

So maybe should I do it programmatically ?

Like inflate my view with my content, evaluate the size of the *LinearLayout* and applied the half to the top margin (and do the same for bottom) ?

Note :

- The vertical grey bar should be centered to **Pin** and **Flag**.
- The vertical grey bar should adapt is size to the size of the two label groups.
- The vertical grey bar should be doted (I will create a CustomView for that, I think).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve this by `ConstraintLayout` as root.

Set top/bottom of **Pin**  and **Flag** to be constrained at top/bottom of Layout in their right(which shows texts). This will center these pictures vertically for those text layout. Then constraint vertical line between **Pin** and **Flag** , so it resize and fill up space between those two. Just remember that you need 1 layout for each set of texts at right.

In addition, I think you make make that dotted line with  [shape xml](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html#Shape) and setting `dashGap` and `dashWidth` of stroke.

Comment: Yeah! That's exactly what I want to do !

Thank you !

I wasn't familiar with constraints ... I'm back on android development since a short time ... since when this constraints was added ?

Comment: PS : thank for the advice with shape xml !
I have totally forget this! It's doing the work

Comment: Another question (sorry) !

I've achieve to place the dotted line between the **Pin** and **Flag**.
But for centered it, I don't know how to achieve this. (Without using *constraintLeft_toLeftOf* **Pin** & *constraintRight_toRightOf* **Pin** because I want it centered regardless to the size of the 2 images width)

Can you help me once more ?

Comment: @tspckr hm...what do you mean by "regardless of size of 2 mages width"? `constraintLeft_toLeftOf` **Pin** & `constraintRight_toRightOf` **Pin** will center dotted line horizontally center of **Pin**. You mean it is possible that **Pin** and **Flag** have different widths? If so, an approach is to constraint left and right of images, so all of them will center. `constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"` and `constraintRight_toLeftOf="<id of text holders>"` for all images will center them horizontally(with width==biggest image width). Now if you center dotted image horizontally, it center all images.

Comment: I aggree, with `constraintLeft_toLeftOf` **Pin** & `constrainRight_toRight` **Pin**, it center the dotted line horizontally, but it seems, horizontally to **Pin**.

Yes, it's exactly what it's mean. In this case **Pin** & **Flag** have the same size.
But I have another View with approximately the same design, but in this case top & bottom images can change (depend of a state) and sometimes it's the top image that is bigger, sometimes it's the bottom image.

Comment: @tspckr Then try approach that I mentioned in my comment and center all images horizontally too. In this case dotted line will appear to be center of all images when all images are centered too(horizontally).

Comment: It seems to be working well !
Thank you ! Now I know what I have to do this weekend, go deeper in constraints :)